# How to implement a one-more-row like Google Reader/Maps, blocking js call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

do you have any example how do it?

I mean:
An ajax call to a web service which waits the data is fully loaded before trying to display it.
On http://twitter-place-finder.grigio.org you need **to press more times the button** before the new data is displayed (from onclick="codeAddress() which doesn't return the result immediatly).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't beleive anyone is actually using blocking calls in JS now. I'm sure it's not a blocking call, maybe they just block user input until the data is received. We do this in our application too. There are different ways to block/unblock user input, for example you can show an invisible iframe atop your page. Another way is to preview and cancel user events. This is the example (GWT):

```
public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
    event.cancel();
}
```